# Permutation and Combination Substring

Tags: permutations, combinations

Sorry i'm quite new to permutation and combination, as i'm actually home studied and i kinda lost somewhere~

Let A={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Permutation of set A end with 6 should be (6-1)! = 5!

The question asked to find how many permutation of set A contains the substring 23? = can i calculate that (6-2)! ?

Then the next question asked to fin how many permutation of set A contains the substring 23 "together in any order?" <-- this part i don't quite understand.

Comment: To handle the case in which $23$ appears in that order, just count the permutations of the $5$ symbols $\{1,23,4,5,6\}$.  For the other, you must also consider the block $32$.

Comment: Any order probably means either "23" or "32".

Comment: It really should say ‘in either order’, since there are only two, but @barak is almost certainly right.

Comment: Mind enlighten me a little, so how to find set A that contains the substring of 23&32

Comment: Haha, after countless of experiment using ABC and ABCD (Yes, i did draw out all possible arrangement of 3! and 4!) and finally i got the answer for my question, Since Substring 23 = 1 object, there fore it's (6-1)! = 120 then for "together in any order @Barakmanos and lulu mentioned 32 = 120+120 = 240! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Consider $23$ as a single package.

Thus now you have $1,23,4,5,6$ five elements to arrange.

Total number of possibilities= $5!=120$.

Second question:

If we consider both substring $23$ and $32$ then total number of possibilities= $2×120=240$.